# Extract and Add specific ARN value into a command repeatedly in Bash Script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a bash script, that runs an aws cli command to grab the list of Secrets Manager Secrets ARNs.. part of script:

```
export SECRETS_ARN_LIST=$(cat terraform_secrets.json | cut -b 21-120 | cut -f1 -d"","" | sed 's/.$//')
```

The value of $SECRETS_ARN_LIST is something like:

```
arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:1244:secret:/test/app/xxxx1
arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:1244:secret:/test/app/xxxx2
arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:1244:secret:/test/app/xxxx3
.
.
.
```

Now, I want to run terraform import command and grab the value of each secret ARN ONE BY ONE.. and put it into

```
terraform import 'module.env-vars.aws_secretsmanager_secret.secrets_manager_env_vars["secret_name"]' arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxx1
```

so then, it should run:

```
terraform import 'module.env-vars.aws_secretsmanager_secret.secrets_manager_env_vars["secret_name"]' arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxx2
```

and then, so on .... ARN with xxxx3

Now, how do I tell bash to get those values of the ARNs one by one and then add them there in place of the ARN?

Comment: Have you tried secret manager data source instead? Example; 

    data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "by-name" {

      name = "example"

    }

then in terraform you could possibly retrieve the arn with `data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.by-name.arn` - I actually haven't tried data sources with secrets manager, so I'm just curious if you explored this yet. reference: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/secretsmanager_secret

Comment: @paulg yes I have tried that .. and that works well. I need to go with this path because I also need to replicate the secrets into another region .. and as the resource is already created I need to bulk import them.